# c atoi() function not working

Tags: c, debugging, atoi

Here is my code. The statement, int value=atoi(ptr[index]) in findMin() function ,gives an error as shown in screenshot.

[image]

The strange thing is that when I use the same atoi() function in main, everything works pretty fine but it screams in findMin!

```
CODE:
void* findMin(void *param); 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    pthread_t t2; //for min
    num=argc;

    /*int index=1; THIS WORKS 
    int value=atoi(argv[index]);*/

    //creating worker thread
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,findMin,argv);

    pthread_join(t2,NULL); //wait for min
    printf("The minimum value is %d\n",min);


    return 0;
}

void* findMin(void *param) 
{
    char *ptr=(char *) param; //casting 
    int index=1;
    min=ptr[1];
    for(index; index<num; index++)
    {
         int value=atoi(ptr[index]); //THIS SCREAMS LIKE HELL!
         if(comp<min) min=value;

    }
}
```

Comment: You need atoi(ptr) or atoi(ptr+index);

Comment: @Claris, I think OP is trying to convert single characters to integers, `ptr+index` will convert the remainder of the string

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: `if(comp<min) min=value;` <-- where's `comp` coming from, and what's the type of `min`?

Comment: Please only post real code - the code above does not even compile (where is `t1` defined, for example ?).

Answer (score 3):

Look at the signature of `atoi`:

```
int atoi(const char *);
```

The function expects the argument to be of the type `char *`. You're passing `ptr[index]`, which is of the type `char`.
The simple solution would be to use a local variable:

```
char digit[2] = "";
```

And then set the first character to the value you want to process:

```
digit[0] = ptr[index];
int value = atoi(digit);
```

because `digit` is of the type `char[]`, it will decay into a pointer when passing it to the function

---

But that would be messy. There's an easier way. The C standard requires numeric characters to be sequential, so a common trick to convert numeric characters to their integer values is to write this:

```
int value = ptr[index] - '0';
```

This works because, in ASCII for example, the numeric value of `'0'` is 48, `'1'` is 49, 2 is 50 and so on. Therefore, if you have a string like this:

```
"1234"
```

and you iterate over each character, subtracting `'0'` from each, you'll get:

```
49 - 48 = 1
50 - 48 = 2
51 - 48 = 3
52 - 48 = 4
```

Basically doing what you want/need

---

## Hang on

I just noticed you're actually iterating over `argv`. Your *cast* is incorrect!

```
char *ptr=(char *) param;
```

Should actually be:

```
char **ptr = param;
```

Because `argv` is a `char **` (pointer to pointer).

You're also doing some weird things here:

If what you're actually trying to do is compare all arguments that were passed and pick the lowest number from them, then this is what you should write:

```
char **ptr= param; //no need for cast, void * is compatible with char **
int i = 1;
min = atoi(ptr[1]);//assuming min is int, because you're assigning value to it later on
for(i; i<num; ++i)
{
     int value = atoi(ptr[i]);
     if(value < min)//replaced comp with value, because I can't see the comp variable anywhere
         min = value;
}
```

Comment: @chux: Changed to double quotes, I do mention _"The C standard requires numeric characters to be sequential"_, and I then go on to use the ASCII values as an example. No need to bombard the OP with info about various character sets like EBCDIC :)